# Deleting layers with gradient properly

Tags: swift, uiview, cagradientlayer

I have UICollectionViewCell with UIView called **gradientView** that is used as a background for labels on it.

This UIView needs to have gradient - it is light and almost transparent at the top of cell and becomes slightly darker in the bottom of the cell (simple linear gradient).

So I created func called addGradient that takes UIView and adds layer with gradient to it.

```
  func addGradient(view : UIView){

    view.backgroundColor = .clear

    let color1 = somecolor1.cgColor
    let color2 = somecolor2.cgColor

    let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame.size = view.frame.size
        gradient.colors = [color1, color2]

    view.layer.addSublayer(gradient) 
}
```

Inside cellForItemAt I call addGradient(cell.gradientView) and the gradient is shown. But I have 2 problems:

1) each cell becomes darker and darker - it seems that layers are added one over another and I don't want it

2) sometimes this gradients are slighly misplaced - I also think that is because I don't delete this layers properly

So how and where I should clear sublayers and maybe my method of adding this gradient inside cellForItemAt is not right?

Answer (score 0):

just a guess on number 1 without seeing more of your code: change frame to bounds

```
 func addGradient(view : UIView){

    view.backgroundColor = .clear

    let color1 = somecolor1.cgColor
    let color2 = somecolor2.cgColor

    let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame.size = view.bounds.size
        gradient.colors = [color1, color2]

    view.layer.addSublayer(gradient) 
}
```